# Cannot convert char to money in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

When I execute the following query

```
floor(Convert(money, @rawMoney) / cc.USDConversionRate)
```

I always get this error, I'm using SQL Server 2000

but if I use

```
 floor( Convert(money,substring(23,10)) / cc.USDConversionRate)
```

then it won't give this error

Comment: What is the value of `@rawMoney`?

Comment: What data type and value is in @rawMoney? I'm guessing it's a longer char value, of which only ten characters after character 23 correspond to a money value.

Comment: sheer.pat18,  and Matt Thrower thank you for your responses,  it is taking 10 digits number like 00007856.0 or 0000001234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only a limited set of non-digit symbols that you can pass to a `money` type variable, such as $. The whole list may be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms179882.aspx).

Check if your raw variable value meets this criterion - if not, that is the error.
e.g. The below does not work if you pass the raw variable to `convert` directly:

```
declare @rawMoney varchar(10) = 'USD 123.45'
select Convert(money,substring(@rawMoney,5,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
select (cast(@rawMoney as money)) from #YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
SELECT CAST(@rawMoney AS MONEY)
```

So it could be like

```
floor( CAST(@rawMoney AS MONEY) / cc.USDConversionRate)
```